# sens du mot « dits »

Tags: sens

Bonjour, je suis en train de lire un article Wikipedia sur l'Époque moderne.

L'article commence.....*'L'époque (ou histoire) moderne , parfois appelée Temps modernes, est une période de l'Histoire qui débute à la fin du Moyen Âge et couvre les trois siècles **dits** « classiques » (XVIe, XVIIe et XVIIIe)1.* '

J'ai du mal à comprendre le sens du mot ***dits*** dans cette phrase. Je l'ai rencontré plusieurs fois et je comprends que ça veut dire 'SO CALLED', mais je ne comprends pas comment décrire et retrouver ce mot dans un dictionnaire. C'est clairement autre chose qu'une conjugaison du verbe dire, mais c'est quoi alors...un adjectif, une préposition? Et comment je fais pour le trouver dans un dictionnaire? Merci.

Answer (score 3):

C'est le participe passé du verbe "dire", utilisé comme adjectif. Il s'accorde en genre et nombre comme tel (ce n'est pas une préposition ni un adverbe).

Le Larousse en ligne cite un usage proche dans les expressions dérivées de "dire", sous l'entrée "DIT + NOM" (voir [ici](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%aatre_dit/25767/locution?q=dit#16000485)).

Wiktionary le référence sous une entrée séparée de "dire", comme un adjectif à part entière: voir [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dit).